# Firebase-Swift How to sum a child values together

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve price value of each product in the cart child, but how should I retrieve it and sum the retrieved value together?

[Picture of my Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxXda.png)

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    refProduct = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).child("cart")
    refProduct.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for cartchild in snapshot.children{
            let snap = cartchild as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.value
            .....


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not store the price as a string, but as a number. You might want to add another field with currency if needed.

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
var sum: Double = 0
refProduct = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("cart")
refProduct.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
   for cartchild in snapshot.children{
       let snap = cartchild as! DataSnapshot
       let data = snap.value as? [String: Any]
       let price = data["ProductPrice"] as? Double ?? 0
       sum += price
   }
   print("Final sum: \(sum)")
}
```

Not really tested, but this is the idea

Comment: thank you. But not working, the price is insert manually, would this affect the retrieve of data?

Comment: not working is not helping. Please be precise otherwise no one can help you. Make the firebase attribute a number, and enter the price without the currency. As I said, its not tested....

Answer (score 0):

Arvidurs is correct about storing the price as an `int` and the currency as a `string`, but the reason the answer isn't working for you is that it doesn't address that you're not correctly retrieving the data you want in the first place.

You have your `cart` folder, and it contains two product folders whose properties you're trying to retrieve. You can't retrieve and unwrap the values contained in those two folders by just referencing the parent `cart` folder. You need to individually access each folder within cart:

```
 Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("cart").child("-Lf59bkQ5X3ivD6ue1SA")
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("cart").child("-Lf5MiEGU357HWTMbxv8")
```

However, for this to work, you'll need access to each products `autoID` value, so you'll need to be storing each new product's `childByAutoID` value into an array or a dictionary so that you have them all available to access whatever data you need.
You'll need to implement this as you're storing the new product to the `cart` folder. I don't know exactly how you're currently saving each product, but you'll need to do something like this when you create your reference that you'll be saving to:

```
let newProductRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("cart").childByAutoId()
       let autoID = newProductRef.key
```

At that point, you'll be able to store `autoID` however you choose, and you'll have access to everything within the `cart` folder, and you can loop through all of your `autoIDs` and get whatever data you need. **Example**:

```
 func getCartPriceSum(finished: @escaping ([String : Double]) -> Void){
       let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        var sum = Double()
        var currency = String()
        for autoID in autoIdArray{
            myGroup.enter()
            let productRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("cart").child(autoID)
            productRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                guard
                    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary,
                    let productPrice = snapshotValue["ProductPrice"] as? Double,
                    let priceCurrency = snapshotValue["PriceCurrency"] as? String//assuming you've adopted Arvidurs' method of storing the price data
                    else {
                        print("productPrice/priceCurreny nil")
                        return
                }

                sum += productPrice
                currency = priceCurrency
            }
       myGroup.leave()
        }

        let priceSum = [currency : sum]
        myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            finished(priceSum)


        }
    }
```

And you could call the function like this:

```
 getCartPriceSum { (priceSum) in
            //do whatever you want with the priceSum
        }
```

The only thing left for you to figure out is how you want to store those autoIDs.